# What is the word for referring to the act of "putting" gas inside a container?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, vocabulary

> - You *put* a solid object into "something".
> - You *pour* a liquid into "something".
> - You ___ a gas into "something".
>
> With that "something" being a three-dimensional container large enough to hold the objects in question.

What is the word for referring to the act of "putting" gas inside a container (for the lack of a better word)?

> Gas is ____  into a pistonless cylinder on a cold day.

Would "filled" work in this case?

Comment: gas (but not gasoline gas) is fed (verb: feed) into pipes and also flows through them.

Comment: gas can also be pumped into or through a system. So can gasoline.

Answer (score 2):

Gas can be **injected**, and you can also **inject** a liquid.

> You **inject** a gas into "something".

So

> Gas is **injected** into a pistonless cylinder on a cold day.

I am not sure what is meant by a "pistonless cylinder", but if the cylinder has a piston the engine may be called "GTI" or "TDI" and in both cases the "I" stands for "injection".

Answer (score 2):

What word you use depends on how exactly the gas is being moved into the container. For example, it is possible for you to:

- [Pump the gas](https://books.google.com/books?id=TZWlgXHMBCgC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq="pumps+air+into".)
- [Blow the gas](https://books.google.com/books?id=AaXpAAAAMAAJ&q="blows+cool+air+into+the+room")
- [Pour the gas](https://youtu.be/FWybQPxKy1U?t=2m33s) (If the gas is heavier than the air around it, of course. Solid things can also be poured if you have many of them, such as sand.)
- etc.

A generic verb you can use is **put**, which is also used with liquids and gasses. The verb **fill** would work if you are making the container full. It can be used in these two ways (i.e. active and passive):

- You fill the container with something
- The container is filled with something

That "something" can be gas, liquid, or solid.

Answer (score 2):

Gas can be "put" into a place by several ways.

Since gas responds to pressure differences, if the pressure drives the gas from place to place, you can say that the gas *flows* into a container. There is no passive form for that, but you can say the gas is *driven* by the pressure.

If you use a pump to force gas into a chamber with a high pressure, then you *pump* or *force* the gas into it.

Another verb, used especially when the container has no gas initially, is *fill*. You can fill a balloon with gas or fill gas into the balloon.

Note that in your question you assume that *pour* is used only for liquid, but you can also pour some solids that are granular, like sand, sugar, or wheat, and technically you can pour a heavier gas into a container which holds a lighter gas. *Pouring* literally describes filling using gravity, and metaphorically can mean any [flowing movement of substance or entities](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pour).

Answer (score 0):

[**Compress**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compress):

> to reduce in size, quantity, or volume as if by squeezing
>   *compress* the air in a closed chamber

Therefore:

> Gas is *compressed* into a pistonless cylinder on a cold day.

Answer (score 0):

Your question uses **into** but if you're also looking for a verb that would work with scenarios that would require **to** (i.e. a conduit rather than a receptacle):

Gas can be **passed**.

> The gas is then passed several times into the pipette containing
>   potassium hydroxide solution...
>
> The gas is then passed over vanadium pentoxide catalyst in a packed bed column reactor in a single or double contact process...
>
> The gas is then passed to a baghouse (or electrostatic precipitator). Baghouses have higher removal efficiencies than precipitators.

Gas can also be **sent into** or **directed into** (something).